# C# error on build

Tags: c#

Hi I am getting an 'Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type'clsWebCamArgs' is less accessible than delegate 'ctrlCamera.WebCamEventHandler'. Can anyone give any insight as to whats wrong with the code below.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PayrollSystem
{
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ctrlCamera), "Camera.ico")] // toolbox bitmap
    [Designer("Sytem.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))] // make composite

    public partial class ctrlCamera : UserControl
    {
        public ctrlCamera(){InitializeComponent();}

        // property variables
        private int m_TimeToCapture_milliseconds = 100;
        private int m_Width = 320;
        private int m_Height = 240;
        private int mCapHwnd;
        private ulong m_FrameNumber = 0;

        // global variables to make the video capture go faster
        private PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs x = new PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs();
        private IDataObject tempObj;
        private Image tempImg;
        private bool bStopped = true;

        // event delegate
        public delegate void WebCamEventHandler(object source, PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs e);
        // fired when a new image is captured
        public event WebCamEventHandler ImageCaptured;

        #region API Declarations

        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [DllImport("avicap32.dll", EntryPoint = "capCreateCaptureWindowA")]
        public static extern int capCreateCaptureWindowA(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hwndParent, int nID);

        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "OpenClipboard")]
        public static extern int OpenClipboard(int hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "EmptyClipboard")]
        public static extern int EmptyClipboard();

        [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "CloseClipboard")]
        public static extern int CloseClipboard();

        #endregion

        #region API Constants
        public const int WM_USER = 1024;

        public const int WM_CAP_CONNECT = 1034;
        public const int WM_CAP_DISCONNECT = 1035;
        public const int WM_CAP_GET_FRAME = 1084;
        public const int WM_CAP_COPY = 1054;
        public const int WM_CAP_START = WM_USER;
        public const int WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT = WM_CAP_START + 41;
        public const int WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOSOURCE = WM_CAP_START + 42;
        public const int WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEODISPLAY = WM_CAP_START + 43;
        public const int WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT = WM_CAP_START + 44;
        public const int WM_CAP_SET_VIDEOFORMAT = WM_CAP_START + 45;
        public const int WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOCOMPRESSION = WM_CAP_START + 46;
        public const int WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = WM_CAP_START + 50;
        #endregion

        #region Control Properties
        public int TimeToCapture_milliseconds
        {
            get { return m_TimeToCapture_milliseconds; }
            set { m_TimeToCapture_milliseconds = value; }
        }

        public int CaptureHeight
        {
            get { return m_Height; }
            set { m_Height = value; }
        }

        public int CaptureWidth
        {
            get { return m_Width; }
            set { m_Width = value; }
        }

        public ulong FrameNumber
        {
            get { return m_FrameNumber; }
            set { m_FrameNumber = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Start and Stop Capture Functions

        public void Start(ulong FrameNum)
        {
            try
            {
                // for safety, call stop, just in case we are already running
                this.Stop();

                // setup a capture window
                mCapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, this.Handle.ToInt32(), 0);

                // connect to the capture device
                Application.DoEvents();
                SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0);
                SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, 0, 0);

                // set the frame number
                m_FrameNumber = FrameNum;

                // set the timer information
                this.timer1.Interval = m_TimeToCapture_milliseconds;
                bStopped = false;
                this.timer1.Start();
            }

            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred while starting the video capture. Check that your webcamera is connected properly and turned on.\r\n\n" + excep.Message);
                this.Stop();
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            try
            {
                // stop the timer
                bStopped = true;
                this.timer1.Stop();

                // disconnect from the video source
                Application.DoEvents();
                SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
            }

            catch (Exception excep)
            { // don't raise an error here.
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region Video Capture Code
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // pause the timer
                this.timer1.Stop();

                // get the next frame;
                SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_GET_FRAME, 0, 0);

                // copy the frame to the clipboard
                SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_COPY, 0, 0);

                // paste the frame into the event args image
                if (ImageCaptured != null)
                {
                    // get from the clipboard
                    tempObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                    tempImg = (Bitmap)tempObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

                    x.WebCamImage = tempImg.GetThumbnailImage(m_Width, m_Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);

                    // raise the event
                    this.ImageCaptured(this, x);
                }

                // restart the timer
                Application.DoEvents();
                if (!bStopped)
                    this.timer1.Start();
            }

            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred while capturing the video image. The video capture will now be terminated.\r\n\n" + excep.Message);
                this.Stop(); // stop the process
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: And for future questions: please reduce your code to the relevant minimum and therefor include other relevant parts. You should have reduced the class `ctrlCamera` to the declaration of your delegate and instead included the declaration of `clsWebCamArgs`. These are the two things your compiler is actually complainig about and therefor were of interest to the SO users who want to help you. It would probably have avoided the downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare

```
public delegate void WebCamEventHandler(object source, PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs e);
```

as `public`, meaning it should be accessible from *everywhere* (even from other assemblies).

But it seems (though I can't find it the code you show) that `PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs` are **not** declared `public`, and so *not* as accessible as the delegate.

So the compiler is giving you an error, because it's not possible to access `WebCamEventHandler` from other assemblies if the type of one of it's arguments is not accessible.

**To solve** this, you can either change the declaration of `WebCamEventHandler` to `internal` or the declaration of `clsWebCamArgs` to `public`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This allowed me to build the project. I changed in the code above to :  internal PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs x = new PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs();   AND   internal delegate void WebCamEventHandler(object source, PayrollSystem.clsWebCamArgs e); AND internal event WebCamEventHandler ImageCaptured;